# No. of terms in a square of polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Is it possible that a square of polynomial has no. of terms less than or equal to the no. of terms of the polynomial?

Comment: If this is a hypothesis... I suppose no proof exist till now......?

Comment: The "hypothesis" I was talking about was meant as a synonym of "assumption". The statement is no hypothesis at all. It can be proved rather easily.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli could you please give a proper proof.. If convenient

Comment: It appears not to be as obvious as I thought. I'll look more into it.